# How to display webform in drupal 7 views

Tags: php, drupal-7

I created webform as block and I'm rendering in template like:

```
<?php print render($page['contact_us']); ?>
```

This working fine in .php, but in views not working.

Comment: This question sounds like a PHP / webserver integration error rather than related to specific programming issue. Consider asking on [ServerFault @ SE](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are rendering region that contains your block, not the block it self and you placed that block in "contact_us" region. But regions are available only in your page template.

Check out how to render block directly:

https://www.drupal.org/node/26502

So, it should be like:

```
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print render($block['content']);
```

And module name should be "webform". You can place this code directly in your view template, where you want your webform block rendered or in pre-precess function and then pass to your template as some variable and print it there.